# Как ограничить диапазон возможных значений переменной int в swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Предположим, есть некоторая переменная a типа Int. Возможно ли как-то ограничить диапазон ее значений, например 10...20? Если в нее пытаются записать меньше 10, то записывать 10. Если больше 20, то 20. Каким образом это грамотно реализовать, например, через get и set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, через свойства-наблюдатели:

```
var intCheck: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if intCheck < 10 {
            intCheck = 10
        } else if intCheck > 20 {
            intCheck = 20
        }
    }
}
```